# address-of (&) and indirection (*) in C

Tags: c

I have a question about the operators : address-of (&) and indirection (*) in C programming .

If

- `var` is a variable of type `int`
- `ptr` is a pointer to `int` and is pointing to `var`

then what would be the value of `ptr`?

Is the result indicating the base address of `var` or the whole 4 bytes (in my platform)? if it is pointing the base address only then why `*ptr` evaluates to the whole contains of `var`? isn't it supposed to show the contains of the base address of `var` only?

Comment: Did you mean to say:"_...then what is the **value** of ptr?_" instead of "_...then what is the **result** of ptr?_"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "then what would be the result of ptr?" Do you intend to print `ptr` as an integer, or to de-reference it, or what? Maybe you could illustrate with a code example?

Comment: yes.. i mean the value of ptr..@machine_1

Comment: i want to print ptr @Lundin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to remember that the type of the *expression* `*ptr` is `int`.  That is, given the declarations

```
int var = 5;
int *ptr = &var;
```

then the following relationships are true:

```
 ptr == &var       // int * == int *
*ptr ==  var == 5  // int   == int   == int
```

Yes, the *value* of `ptr` is the address of the first byte<sup>1</sup> of `var`.  However, the *expression* `*ptr` refers to the whole `int` value stored in `var`.

Pointers are an *abstraction* of a memory address with additional type semantics such that pointer operations work the same way on all types.  If `ptr` points to a 4-byte `int`, then `*ptr` evaluates to that 4-byte `int` value.  If it points to an 8-byte `double`, then `*ptr` evaluates to that 8-byte `double` value.

---

1. Where the "first byte" may be either the most significant byte (big-endian architecture) or least significant byte (little-endian architecture).  C hides the distinction behind the `int` type abstraction so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

`ptr`, being an `int *`, points to the whole `int`, or as you put it, the whole `sizeof(int)` bytes.

`(unsigned char *)ptr` points to the "base address", as you put it.

`ptr` and `(unsigned char *)ptr` will have the same *numeric value* on all common CPU architectures, which demonstrates that the difference between pointing to the "whole" integer and pointing to just the "base address" is entirely a matter of what type the pointer has.  It's vital that you understand that two variables with different types can still have the same numeric value.

Comment: Nice explanation for how pointing to the whole target object is an aspect of the *interpretation* of a pointer according to its type, not, generally, an inherent property of the pointer value or its representation.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer variable `ptr` will contain the address where `var` starts, i.e. the address of the first byte of `var`.  If you dereference `ptr` as `*ptr` you will get the value of `var`.

Assuming a `int` is 4 bytes, using `*ptr` "knows" to read the next 4 bytes  because of the type of the pointer.  Since `ptr` has type `int *` this means `*ptr` has type `int`, so the next 4 bytes are read as an `int`.

For example:

```
int var = 4;
int *ptr = &var;
printf("ptr = %p\n", (void *)ptr);
printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
printf("&var = %p\n", (void *)&var);
printf("var = %d\n", var);
```

Output:

```
ptr = 0x7ffc330b4484
*ptr = 4
&var = 0x7ffc330b4484
var = 4
```

Comment: I think OP is asking: Is the value of `ptr` the address of the 1st byte of the `int` variable or is it the addresses of all the bytes combined, and if it contains only the address of the first byte, then why de-referencing it gives the entire value of the `int` variable and not a fragment of it, i.e. the value at the first byte.

Comment: @machine_1 I see whee you're coming from.  Added more detail to clarify.

Comment: @machine_1 exactly

Answer (score 0):

Like any other type, pointer is also a type.

A pointer, which is eligible to be dereferenced, has to point to a complete type. Each type has a defined (either pre or user) size, so the dereference takes into account of the size of the type of object a pointer points to.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is
>   undefined.

Let's see the below graphics to understand it better.

Say,

```
int x = 10;
int * px = &a;
```

and, in that platform, `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Now, in memory, it would look like

```
          +-------------------------------------------+
          |                                           |
          |              int x  = 10;                 |
          |                                           |
          +-------------------------------------------+

      0x1000                                        0x1004


           +------------------------------------------+
           |                                          |
           |     pointer * px  = &x; (0x1000)         |
           |                                          |
           +------------------------------------------+
```

- Now, the whole block of memory , `0x1000` to `0x1003` (upto beginning of address `0x1004`) is allocated for that variable `x` of type `int`.
- `px` is the pointer, pointing to the start of that memory block. Also, while defining `px`, we told compiler that it would point to an `int`, so compiler knows, the memory block, which is stored at `px`, has storage for 4 bytes, and to get the data during indirection (using the `*` operator), we need to read all the 4 bytes and then return the result.

Thus, while writing `*px`, compiler reads all the 4 bytes and returns the value.

Comment: This is all true but I don't see how it answers the question; if it does, it does so only in terms that are likely to be well over OP's head.

Comment: @zwol Tried to make it better, worthy?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the result indicating the base address of var or the whole 4 bytes (in my platform)? if it is pointing the base address only then why *ptr evaluates to the whole contains of var? isn't it supposed to show the contains of the base address of var only?

As you have mentioned, the platform you are using has `4` byte size `int`.
*`var` is a variable of type `int`*:

```
    100   101   102   103
var -------------------------
    |     |     |     |     |
    -------------------------
     byte1 byte2 byte3 byte4

where, 100 - 104 are the address of byte1-byte4 respectively.
```

*`ptr` is a pointer to `int` and is pointing to `var`.*
when you do `int *ptr = &var;`, it means something like this:

```
   ptr              100   101   102   103
   --------     var -------------------------
   | &var |-------->|     |     |     |     |
   --------         -------------------------
                     byte1 byte2 byte3 byte4
```

The type of `ptr` is `int *` i.e. pointer to an integer. So, the type of `*ptr` is `int`. That means, when you dereference `ptr` it gives the value at the address `ptr` is pointing to and its type indicate the type of value which is `int` in your case. Thats why, `*ptr` evaluate to whole `int` and not just the base address.

---

Note that if you do this

```
char *c_ptr = (char *)&var;
```

it changes the **interpretation** of address of `var` when accessed using `c_ptr` and `*c_ptr` will be interpreted as `char`. Though, the address at which `ptr` and `c_ptr` pointing to are numerically same.

Check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int var = 50;
    int *i_ptr = &var;
    char *c_ptr = (char *)&var;

    printf ("address of var: %p\n", (void *)&var);
    printf ("i_ptr: %p\n", (void *)i_ptr);
    printf ("i_char: %p\n\n", (void *)c_ptr);
    printf ("value of var: %d\n", var);
    printf ("value of *i_ptr: %d\n", *i_ptr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf ("Address of byte[%zu]: %p, ", i, (void *)&c_ptr[i]);
        printf ("byte[%zu]: %c\n", i, c_ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output on little-endian architecture:

```
address of var: 0x7ffeea3ac9f8
i_ptr: 0x7ffeea3ac9f8          <========\
i_char: 0x7ffeea3ac9f8         <========/ the address pointing to is same

value of var: 50
value of *i_ptr: 50
Address of byte[0]: 0x7ffeea3ac9f8, byte[0]: 2     <========= 50th character of ascii
Address of byte[1]: 0x7ffeea3ac9f9, byte[1]: 
Address of byte[2]: 0x7ffeea3ac9fa, byte[2]: 
Address of byte[3]: 0x7ffeea3ac9fb, byte[3]:
```

Output on big-endian architecture:

```
address of var: ffbffbd0
i_ptr: ffbffbd0
i_char: ffbffbd0

value of var: 50
value of *i_ptr: 50
Address of byte[0]: ffbffbd0, byte[0]: 
Address of byte[1]: ffbffbd1, byte[1]: 
Address of byte[2]: ffbffbd2, byte[2]: 
Address of byte[3]: ffbffbd3, byte[3]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal value/representation of `ptr`  is, in general, unspecified.  The specification says that only if you dereference it, the value has some sense.  Everything you can be told about it, is that it is some information that allows the computer to find the value of the referenced type.

The compiler stores, with the pointer type, the referenced type for values of that pointer type.  The idea is to be able to do pointer arithmetic (a C specific powerful idea) and to be able to use the values *pointed to* in expressions.

But the standard doesn't say anything about the internal representation of the actual pointer value.

This is specified so, to allow freedom for different architectures to implement *address of* values as best they can.

This makes it possible to implement e.g. in general Intel 32bit processors a pointer as a `segment:offset` data type, which, as such, has not a valid interpretation as a single number.  In a non-transparent virtual memory architecture, a pointer could require to specify the disk device, block number and offset in block, where the pointed value is stored, and so, using a disk device, block number, and an offset value can make difficult to interpret the whole thing as a number.  One can argue that the `segment:offset` value can be interpreted as a number (as it was in old 8086 processors, in with you could get the linear address by shifting left 4 bits the segment selector, then adding the offset).  But if you do that in modern virtual memory architectures, you'll find that there's no easy way of computing the actual memory address if you consider that some of the info is hidden by the operating system.  The `segment` selector is only a descriptor to a possibly large amount of OS hidden meta-information (where the segment is located in linear address space, how much it extends, if you have permissions to deallocate the pointer as data or executable code, etc.)

Indeed, **two different pointers *can dereference* the same final pointed data**.  Assume two different pointers that have been generated by different means, composed of different segment selectors and same or different offsets, but that map, after translation, to overlapping segments that *finally point to the same physical memory location*.  In that case, there's no possibility even to compare such pointers, but when you access one the referenced values, you are actually getting the same data from both pointers.  Dealing with this kind of pointers can make a pain for you, and force you to have to be very careful when doing pointer arithmetic with such pointers (read about `far` pointers in old Microsoft compilers), but that's not an impediment to implement a C compiler on such an architecture.